# How to remove specific tags from with a DIV?

Tags: jquery, find

Have found a mixed bag of solutions that don't seem to work.  I'm loading the HTML of a particular page, and want to extract the HTML from within an identified DIV - this works fine, but trying to remove an unidentified H3 tag from within the remaining HTML (and retain the following UL/LIs) seems to be impossible: I've tried everything Google has to offer, and can get either no results, or only the contents of the H3 tag.  I'm trying to get the HTML of the UL list, including the UL tags.

```
/* variable html is the result of an AJAX load of the web page of interest*/
/* I know the first line below is not correct */
/* but it demonstrates the chain of events that I'm trying to accomplish*/

var theStuffIWant = $(html).find("#tab-2").remove("h3").html();

<div id="tab-2">
    <h3>Heading to get rid of</h3>
    <ul>The list I want to keep
         <li>List item to keep</li>
         <li>List item to keep</li>
         <li>List item to keep</li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See http://jsfiddle.net/ewjBp/

The `remove()` can't be used in chaining, because it returns the elements that were removed.

So you need to split: first remove the elements, then check the `html()` of the div, which was ridden of all `h3`.

---

**Edit**

http://jsfiddle.net/ewjBp/5/

So, first you create a new Jquery object by wrapping the html you want (e.g. `$(html)`).

As @pete stated, this **won't** be inserted into DOM. DOM is the in-memory representation of the page, accessible to Javascript, meaning that `$(html)` won't be added to the page structure representation.

Then just find the headers (with [children()](http://api.jquery.com/children/)), and replace with nothing.

I suggest you read about [replaceWith()](http://api.jquery.com/replaceWith/), and the fact that it **returns the old object** instead. That's why I discard return value. It's not necessary, `html` will be changed anyway in the above code.

Also, `html.html()` discards the outer HTML element in `html`, which is the DIV container in this example.

Comment: Please don't just link to a jsfiddle; include your javascript inline (this isn't just for the person asking the question, but for those that might find it later, too).

Comment: Your example works as I want it to, but I get[object Object]. How do I apply that to my variable "html".  (Sorry, just learning this stuff).

Comment: My work around was to create a temporary, hidden DIV to contain my te HTML from my source page, then your example worked perfectly - so first, THANKS!!, but now I wonder is this the right way of doing it, or can i operate directly on the var "html"?

Answer (score 4):

Since you're only concerned with the `ul`, skip the `h3` and extract what only you want:

```
$('<div />').append($('#tab-2').find('ul')).html();
```

or

```
$('#tab-2').find('ul'); //to return them as a jQuery object.
```

Comment: Your first suggestion is actually incorrect, as it would remove the surround `<ul>` from the HTML.

Comment: Yup. Realized that when you pointed it out. Fixed by appending to a new div and extracting HTML of new div. Thanks!

Comment: Don't have the luxury of adding another div...the HTML I have to work from is out of my control, but thanks

Comment: I think you misunderstand. `$('<div />')` creates a new `div` in memory, unattached to the DOM. `.append($('#tab-2').find('ul'))` extracts the `ul` and content and inserts it into the unattached `div`. `.html()` then returns the `innerHTML` of the unattached `div` (the content of interest). At no point is the unattached `div` ever inserted into the DOM, the memory just gets reclaimed by the garbage collector on routine exit.

Answer (score 0):

Get an array of all H3s within that item, then loop through and remove them.

```
var eles = $("#tab-2").getElementsByTagName("h3");
for(var i in eles)
    $("#tab-2").removeChild(eles[i]);
```

Comment: This just returns "[object Object]"

Answer (score 0):

I can't figure out how to comment on the previous but I'd suggest fully using JQuery's selectors:

```
$('#tab-2 h3').each(function(idx) {
    $(this).remove();
}
```

Code untested but you get the gist of it, I hope.